# Dunford Pettis Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Suppose $L_1([0,1],\lambda)=L_1(\lambda)$ is the set of all $1$-integrable functions on $[0,1]$.

$$S=\{(f_1,f_2)\in L_1^2(\lambda) |0\leq f_1+f_2\leq 1, a.e. \}$$

By Dunford Pettis theorem, we know that for $j=1,2$,

$$S_j=\{f_j\in  L_1(\lambda) |0\leq  f_j\leq 1, a.e.  \} $$

is weakly compact with respect to weak topology $\sigma(L_1(\lambda),L_{\infty}(\lambda))$, can I conclude that $S$ is also weakly compact  with respect to weak topology $\sigma(L_1^2(\lambda),L_{\infty}^2(\lambda)$)?

Comment: Hint: the product of two compact sets is compact (you'll need to verify that a certain topology is the same as a certain product topology) and a closed subset of a compact set is compact.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich $S$ is not the product of $S_1$ and $S_2$: while functions in $S_i$ are non-negative, $(f_1,f_2)\in S$ does not imply $f_1\ge0$ and $f_2\ge 0$.

Comment: @daw True. But only because I misread the problem. Given that the problem as stated is so obviously wrong, I tend to suspect that what the OP _meant_ was the way I read it: $S$ is the set of $f_1+f_2$ such that $f_j\ge0$ and $f_1+f_2\le 1$.

Comment: Hi, sorry  for my mistakes, here $\{ S=(f_1,f_2)| f_1\geq 0, f_2\geq 0, and 0\leq f_1+f_2\leq 1, a.e.\}$

Comment: Hi, would product topolgy the sum of L1 norms work? I also don't figure out why  we need a continuous image of compact set is compact.

Answer (score 1):

No this set is not weak compact: The pair of constant functions $p_n=(n,-n)$ is in $S$, but certainly $(p_n)$ does not have a weakly converging subsequence (and the set cannot by weakly compact).

Comment: Hi, thanks for indicating this error. I have revised the problem to include $f_1\geq 0, f_2\geq 0$.